# How to use Select-String to return a Hashtable of (key)file name and (value)array of match values in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to search inside a directory for files that match a specific regex, and save the file name and match value inside a hash table. A file can contain multiple matches but only one match per line. Some match values will also be the same for multiple files, but only one needs to be kept. With a foreach loop it would be fairly easy, but i'd like to use Select-String as in my experience it's alot faster.

I already have this code that saves matches inside an array:

```
$regex = [regex]"test\s+(\w+)"  
$path = $PSScriptRoot
$matches = Get-ChildItem $path -filter "*.txt" | Select-String -Pattern $regex | foreach-object {$_.matches.groups[1].value} | Select-Object -Unique
```

I know selecting the file name would be done with `| select name` but how would i combine this with the match value?

A simplified example with two files "file1.txt" and "file2.txt" in the script directory would look like this:

file1.txt

```
abcd
test string1
```

file2.txt

```
abcd
test string1
test string2
test string3
```

Current $matches:

```
@('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
```

What i'd like $matches to hold:

```
@{'file1.txt'=@('string1'); 'file2.txt'=@('string2', 'string3')}
```

Comment: `Select-String` returns a `MatchInfo` object and `Select-Object` returns a `pscustomobject`.  If you want to store these into a `hashtable`, you'll need to store the outputs of `sls` and fill it in when needed

Comment: This wont give you a hashtable - which I don't think you want anyway - but what you should look at is Calculated properties which will give you the paired output.

Comment: So the match should be the key and the filename the value? As keys are unique just suppres errors to eliminate dublettes. Otherwise an example could help understand what you're after.

Comment: Please provide an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with sample input and expected results.

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: Did you read the link about how to create an MCV? How would I take what you have posted and reproduce the problem that you are having?

Comment: @EBGreen Added more information.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hashtable

- key(file)
- value(array of strings from file which are unique across all files)
- Added the following string to file1.txt to aid in testing

  - test string4

#### file1.txt

```
abcd
test string1
test string4
```

#### file2.txt

```
abcd
test string1
test string2
test string3
```

#### provided variables...

```
$regex = [regex]"test\s+(\w+)"  
$path = $PSScriptRoot
```

#### one liner...

```
$matches = $($find = (Get-ChildItem $path -filter "*.txt" | Select-String -Pattern $regex | foreach-object {@{$_.Filename = $_.matches.groups[1].value}}) | Sort-Object Values -Unique;foreach ($file in ($find.Keys | Sort -Unique)) {@{$file = $($find | where {$_.Keys -eq $file}).Values}})
```

#### one liner expanded...

```
$matches = $(
    $find = (
        Get-ChildItem $path -filter "*.txt" | 
            Select-String -Pattern $regex | 
                foreach-object {
                    @{$_.Filename = $_.matches.groups[1].value}
                }
    ) | Sort-Object Values -Unique
    foreach ($file in ($find.Keys | Sort -Unique)) {
        @{
            $file = $(
                $find | where {$_.Keys -eq $file}
            ).Values
        }
    }
)
```

#### Usage and Output

```
$matches.Keys
file1.txt
file2.txt

$matches.Values
string4
string1
string2
string3

$matches.'file1.txt'
string4

$matches.'file2.txt'
string1
string2
string3

$matches
Name                           Value
----                           -----
file1.txt                      {string4}
file2.txt                      {string1, string2, string3}
```

Comment: Corrected and retested.